# Label WordWrap always wrapping the last two words

Tags: ios, xamarin, label, word-wrap

Beginner on the Xamarin platform and curious why would my Label is wrapping the last two words instead of the last word only.

I've used the `Label` from the Xamarin From with `LineBreakMode="WordWrap"` now the resulting view is described below:

[image]

As you can see that the last two words are wrapped instead of just the last word. Also, it works perfectly in Android, only the iOS build is having this issue.

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="{StaticResource MediumSpacingAll}">
      <Label Text="Thank you for joining..." TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="40" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the visualization of the label dimension inside the parent view.

[image]

Comment: try changing the HorizontalOptions to "FillAndExpand"

Comment: @Jason Did not work. It is the same issue.

Comment: try setting a background color on the label so you can visualize how wide it actually is

Comment: @Jason Added an image above, as you can see there is space for it.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Does my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Custom Renderer to set the content align in iOS .

```
using System;


using Foundation;
using UIKit;

using xxx;
using xxx.iOS;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Label),typeof(MyLabelRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyLabelRenderer:LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                string content = Control.Text;

                NSMutableAttributedString attributedString = new NSMutableAttributedString(content);

                NSMutableParagraphStyle paragraphStyle = new NSMutableParagraphStyle();
                paragraphStyle.Alignment = UITextAlignment.Left;

                attributedString.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.ParagraphStyle,paragraphStyle,new NSRange(0,content.Length));

                Control.AttributedText = attributedString;
            }
        }

    }
}
```